# How do I create an array by applying a function to the index of each element?

Tags: functions, programming, list-manipulation

I am looking for something like [`matrix(m, n, f)`, but for Mathematica rather than MuPAD, and for arrays rather than matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/matrix.html#stdlib-matrix-ex5).  That is, I'm looking for a(n efficient) way of doing this without for-loops:

```
ret = zeros(m, n);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        ret(i, j) = some_function([i, j]);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of ways:

```
f[x_, y_] := y*x^2

SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> f[i, j], {3, 3}] // Normal

Array[f, {3, 3}]

Table[f[x, y], {x, 3}, {y, 3}]

(*
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 8, 12}, {9, 18, 27}}

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 8, 12}, {9, 18, 27}}

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 8, 12}, {9, 18, 27}}
```

*)

If you already have the array (say in this example a 3x3 zeroes) and you want to go over it and apply some function based on indices (and perhaps existing values):

```
array = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];

(* example fn, takes current value and index *)
f[curval_, idx_] := curval + Total@idx

MapIndexed[f[#, #2] &, array, {2}]

(* {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}} *)
```

Comment: Well covered. +1